# Bootstrap:How do I disable sorting for only one column in Bootstrap Grid View

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap:I have a checkbox column as the first column in the bootstrap grid.I do not need sorting for this column.How to disable sorting for only this column?

Comment: what you mean by bootstrap gridview? bootstrap does not have gridview... asp.net gridview with bootstrap style?

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html .U can refer this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code works for disabling columns,by setting the orderable property to false to required column. #example is grid view Id.

```
  $('#example').DataTable({
        "columns": [{
            "orderable": false
        }, {
            "orderable": true
        }, {
            "orderable": true
        }, {
            "orderable": true
        }, {
            "orderable": true
        }, {
            "orderable": true
        }, {
            "orderable": true
        }]
    });
```